# Css Stripes not showing correctly in microsoft edge browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with stripes not showing correctly in Microsoft Edge browser.

```
.post_regular.custom_lf {
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
130deg,
#2C4632,
#2C4632 5px,
#26315D 5px,
#26313D 10px 
 ); 
}
```

Chrome: [This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuHEv.png)

MS Edge Browser: [Microsoft Edge browser displays it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPYV1.png)

It works fine in other browsers just not Microsoft Edge browser.

Comment: Post some HTML as well. Better yet, create a code snippet.

Comment: This works flawlessly in Edge 42. You more than likely have other outstanding discrepancies affecting layout. Hard to provide you feedback with only a simple background gradient, which is supported by all [major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients)

Comment: @notKnown44 As https://jsfiddle.net/ use this !

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I was able to solve it. all I did was that I made a stripes image `background-image: url("/Stripes.png"); background-repeat: repeat; }` works great in all browsers